# how to remove nested entry in a nested map using dot notation

Tags: java

I have a nested map, something like this:
`map.get("employee").get("address").remove("city")`

Is there a way to remove the city entry using a key like "employee.address.city"? So I am looking for something like `MapUtil.remove(map,"employee.address.city")`

Comment: You just need to split your `String` and then navigate your `Map`. This implies you need to use a `Map<String, Object>`. Why do you need three nested `Map`s? This sounds a lot like an `Object` fail.

Comment: Not out-of-the-box, but unless you're doing something funky with the actual map values, it's a simple recursive function. You could also use an EL (Expression Language) like OGNL, MVEL, EL 3, etc. but that seems a little bulky if this is your only usecase.

Comment: @BoristheSpider That nested map is created by deserializing a JSON file in Jackson

Comment: Then use a library for it, like Jackson or Gson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not natively, no, though you could write yourself a method to parse your extended map key using `String.split("\\.")`, like this:

```
public void nestedRemove(Map map, String keyToRemove)
{
    String string = "employee.address.city";
    String[] keys = string.split("\\.");
    Map subMap = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < keys.length -1; i++)
    {
        subMap = subMap.get(keys[i]);
    }
    subMap.remove(keys[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why do the `if` every iteration? Just change the loop to `for (i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; ++i)` and then use the last element in the array to do the remove after the loop is done.

Answer (score 5):

Java 8 library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics) can do this, it wraps a nested map/collection (amongst other types) structure and allows null-safe reasoning without static typing.

```
Dynamic.from(map).get("employee").get("address").asMap().remove("city");
```

We wrap the map to obtain our Dynamic instance, #get now returns other Dynamic instances representing the child, or absence of that child. As such this is null-safe.

For convenience we can also use #dget to split a get into many, and perhaps #maybe to handle the cases where the employee or address don't exist without exception:

```
Dynamic.from(map).dget("employee.address")
    .maybe().asMap()
    .ifPresent(address -> address.remove("city"));
```

See more examples https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own method to do this, although you'd be likely to have to resort to a fair amount of casting. You'd probably just split on dots, then keep calling `get` (and remembering the result for the next step) until you got to the last part, at which point you'd call `remove` instead... remembering to check for a null return from `get` at every step.

I don't know of anything built into a third party library to do this - which isn't to say it's *nowhere*, of course.